# Can we make the Moon fall using nukes?

Tags: moons, nuclear

Current technology.

Our Moon is drifting a few centimeters further away every year as a result of tides. Moon exerts gravitational pull on everything on Earth including bodies of water such as an ocean, when the ocean bulge the force of gravity becomes stronger and pull on the moon much harder. Inevitably this acceleration cause our natural satellite to drift further away.

I'm curious if there is any way to decelerate the Moon and make it fall to Earth using the energy produce by nuclear reaction alone? If not why not?

Note:
To qualify the "Moon falls" the orbital speed must be below 3000 km per hour!  As usual the answer with greatest mean deceleration wins.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G01NoaTM46o watch this!

Comment: I would suggest removing the phrase "using nukes" from your title question. A nuke is a nuclear weapon. using nuclear reactions could include fusion or fission rocket engines. Sadly, it looks like a duplicate too.